# Nonlocal return from lambda?

Tags: java-8, option-type

I am very new to programming so be gentle please! :D

```
public void test(Optional<String> testString){
    testString.ifPresent(s -> {
        //do stuff...
        System.out.println("Exit method");
        return;
    });
    //Log if it was not present
    Logger.log("...");
}
```

Here you have a code snippet. If the optional is present I do some stuff and want to exit the method by just calling return. I now wonder why my logger logs something although the testString is present. Can someone maybe point out what I'm missing please ? Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you do:

```
 testString.ifPresent(s -> {
        //do stuff...
        System.out.println("Exit method");
        return;
    });
```

You return from a lambda function, and not from the test(), as you expect.

Try using isPresent:

```
    if (testString.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("Exit method");
        return;
    }
    //Log if it was not present
    System.out.println("Not present");
```

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for pointing out. Is there a way to end the test method from within the lambda ?

Comment: The only way I'm aware of is to throw a RuntimeException of some kind. Not nice.

Comment: Alright, I will go with your suggestion then. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: You can use `CompleteableFuture` to wait for computations in lambdas, including async ones.

Comment: That's an excellent idea, I think you should post it as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

With Java 9 Optional will have the method

```
void ifPresentOrElse(Consumer<? super T> action, Runnable emptyAction)
```

which handles the else part aswell. For now you should stick with the already accepted answer.